# How to show iphone app icon on lock screen same as camera on bottom left

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

How to show iPhone app icon on lock screen same as camera on bottom left.
Is there any framework required to implement or just go to settings page in iPhone.
How to do it exactly please described step wise.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You might have seen in certain circumstances some app icons are showing up in the bottom left corner of lock screen. That is an iOS 9 feature. that may be because of following reason.

- You're near a business or iBeacon that is broadcasting its location and you have a corresponding app installed, such as being near a Starbucks store; drag the icon to the top of the screen to launch that app.
- You're able to use Handoff to take over from an app on another device. For example, if you're composing an email message on your iPhone and switch to your iPad, drag the Mail icon that appears on the iPad up to load the message you were working on in the Mail app.
- When you insert a headphone jack into the device's headphone port, or connect to a Bluetooth stereo, iOS 9 guesses you want to listen to something and displays the icon of the last audio app you used when connecting headphones or pairing to that particular speaker. Drag the icon up to open that app.

Reference : http://www.imore.com/how-use-home-screen-and-lock-screen-your-iphone-6s

Apart from these, there can be more reasons, like if you are using an application at a particular location/time for few times/days, then iOS will suggest the app once you reach that location or at particular time of every day.

Answer (score 0):

you can't do this kind of stuff from code or from your application. It is apple's restriction. and you can't change it or replace with another app. it is by default camera app.